Definition of an ordinal in the naive set theory
I would like to see step-by-step derivation of Burali-Forti paradox (with von Neumann ordinals) in an axiomatized naive set theory. In order to do such a derivation I need to define the naive "set" of all von Neumann ordinals Ord, but I am not sure how to do that in the context of the naive set theory.
Let me first axiomatize the naive set theory:

Unrestricted comprehension schema -- $\exists y\forall x(x\in y \leftrightarrow \varphi(x))$ (here I am not sure if it is generally allowed that $y$ occurs in $\varphi$ or not)
Extensionality -- $\forall z(z\in x \leftrightarrow z\in y)\leftrightarrow x=y$

What would be the comprehension instance for the naive "set" Ord of all von Neumann ordinals?

Well, one way would to derive Russell's paradox, and then conclude that there is a set of all ordinals, since from a contradiction everything follows ;)

This issue is discussed here on wikipedia.

@Joe I do not understand. In order to derive $q$ from Russell's contradiction I need to firstly know how to write down $q$ and I am asking how to "write down" the set of all ordinals

Not sure why you want to use an inconsistent theory, but you can use the usual definition of an ordinal: transitive and well-ordered by $\in$.

@LeeMosher I meant von Neumann ordinals, and on the wikipedia it is written in such a way that I honestly do not know how to write down the wanted comprehension instance

Sorry, my first comment was meant as a kind of joke. A set $x$ is an ordinal if it is transitive and well-ordered by $\in$. Both of these conditions can be written as formulas in the language of set theory, although actually doing so is rather tedious. For example, $x$ is transitive means $\forall y\forall z(((y\in z)\land (z\in x))\to y\in x)$ (in English, "if $y\in z$ and $z\in x$, then $y\in x$).

To say that $x$ is well-ordered by $\in$ means that (i) for all $a\in x$, it is not the case that $a\in a$ [irreflexivity], (ii) for all $a,b\in x$, either $a\in b$ or $b\in a$ [asymmetry], (iii) for all $a,b,c\in x$, if $a\in b$ and $b\in c$, then $a\in c$ [transitivity], (iv) for all $x_0$ such that $x_0\subseteq x$ and $x_0$ is nonempty, $x_0$ has a least element with respect to $\in$. Writing out the first three conditions in the language of set theory is routine, and writing out the fourth condition just takes a little more perseverance.

So, eventually, you can write a very long formula $\mathrm{ordinal}(x)$ saying that "$x$ is an ordinal", which will have the shape "$\mathrm{transitive}(x)\land\mathrm{wellordered}(x)$". And then the formula saying "there exists a set $X$ of all ordinals" will be $\exists X(\forall x(x\in X\leftrightarrow\mathrm{ordinal}(x)))$.

By the way, essentially every notion encountered in axiomatic set theory can be expressed in the language of ZFC – it's just that doing so would take a lot of ink. There are a few technical conditions investigated by modern set theorists that are not expressible, I believe, but that's definitely the exception to the norm, and I can't remember any examples off the top of my head.

@Joe thanks a lot :)

There are a few equivalent definitions of "(von Neumann) ordinal." The simplest one for many applications, including this setting, is the following:

$x$ is an ordinal iff $x$ is a hereditarily transitive set; that is, $x$ is transitive and each element of $x$ is transitive.

This is quickly expressed in the formal language of set theory (compare with e.g. "transitive and well-ordered by $\in$," which is a bit messier):
$$Ord(x):\equiv [\forall y\forall z(y\in x\wedge z\in y\implies z\in x)]\wedge [\forall y\forall z\forall w(y\in x \wedge z\in y \wedge w\in z\implies w\in y)].$$
Naive comprehension applied to $Ord(x)$ yields a set of all hereditarily transitive sets; it's easy to check that this set is hereditarily transitive, and so is an element of itself. That is not immediately a contradiction, since we don't have the axiom of foundation in our naive set theory, but it is the first step towards the Burali-Forti paradox. (There are a few ways to wrap things up; personally, my favorite is to look at the modified formula $Ord'(x):\equiv Ord(x)\wedge x\not\in x$, apply comprehension to that, and show that the resulting set is and is not an element of itself.)

can I really use this definition in this setting? you stated that we do not have the axiom of foundation, then the property of being hereditarily transitive does not entail being well-founded in this setting, doesn't it? am I just dumb?

@kevin.spacey That's a good point, but since your goal is to derive a contradiction anyways I don't think it matters: the class of hereditarily transitive non-self-containing sets yields a paradoxical situation regardless of whether we have foundation. That said, if you want to work with a definition of "ordinal" which doesn't at least motivation-wise presuppose foundation, then yes you'll want to follow Joe's suggestion instead of mine.

all clear, I think your answer is even more than I hoped for, thanks!
